Sonoma, wifi password is human-untypable in password manager
I have a password that's maybe 100 characters. It is for a wifi ssid in my own home. I store this password in a password manager. I am unable to paste it into the password field. I am unable to reasonably change this password (many IoT devices would need to be changed as well). Is there a reason that Apple prevents me from pasting the password, or is there no reason at all? Can this security feature be turned off or disabled?

Assume you are aware that the marginal benefit of longer passwords is close to zero for 30+ characters. Anyway, which password field are  you talking about, the one showing up when joining a WiFi network?

Can you paste anything into the password field? Can you paste the password from the manager into somewhere else, like a TextEdit document? I've certainly copied and pasted passwords from Apple's own password manager into macOS fields, so I'd be surprised if this one were different. I'd agree that maybe 100 characters provides no greater security at a greater cost to practicality.

It may also be helpful to know which password manager you are using. I know that Bitwarden has disabled the ability to copy a password from a mobile device to a computer.

@nohillside The only benefit to having shorter passwords I can see, is to give Apple an excuse to do stupid shit like blocking copy-paste. The password field I'm talking about is the wifi password itself, when you connect to an access point.

@benwiggy Nothing pastes into the field. This has apparently been disabled for some time, I just never noticed. Yes, the password pastes everywhere else. It is disabled in the dialog for putting in a wifi password, either from the menu, or from System Settings. Go ahead and test if yourself, you could just pick some random wifi and try it.

@agarza I'm using Enpass, but this is from the password manager on the same iMac. No cross-device pasting.

I just did some impromptu testing and it looks as though the field will only accept 63 characters and nothing more.

If you can't paste anything into the Wifi password, then that's definitely non-standard and something wrong at your end. I concur with the others that you should be able to paste up to 63 chars.

Paste the first 62 characters and test, then try 63. Also, if your router uses WEP authentication, you might be able to convert the phrase to hex and enter that.

@benwiggy Just tested this on my Macbook (not the iMac). I clicked the wifi icon in the menubar, went to "other", dialog pops up. Try to paste your username as the password... does not accept it. This is two Macs that I can confirm do not allow pasting the password. If you believe mine to be nonstandard, please attempt this test yourself, it takes less than 10 seconds (don't actually need to connect to another wifi for it). This seems standard across all modern macs, and I find hints of it being the case on Stackoverflow and other sites going back as far as 2012.

I tested copying a string of text from BBEdit, of different lengths, and it worked perfectly up to 63 chars. This on two Macs. Where are you copying your username from? Perhaps the string contains chars that aren't allowed in the WPA2 spec...?

I see the same as benwiggy. If you use another user account on your Mac (create one if necessary), does it still not work? If you reboot into safe mode, does this change anything?

I use wireless keyboards for both my iMac and my Macbook. Got to wondering if this was a bluetooth thing. Tried with the Macbooks builtin keyboard... same problem. I happened to have it unmuted at the time. Attempting to paste even small strings into the wifi password field produces the "you can't do that" tha-dunk noise. This is when I choose "Other" as the wifi access point.

Good call with the wireless keyboard, actually. Did you try with safe boot and/or new user account? And I assume you try to paste a short word, not a 100 char string.

@nohillside I don't remember what I pasted, but it was just some word copied off a webpage, this one I think. 7 or 8 characters max. There are other people describing this same thing in various forums going back almost ten years... one of them was Stackoverflow. But I couldn't find details or definitive answers. But I'm not calling anyone here a liar either... I just don't understand the discrepancy. Do I hate some weird-assed setting turned on that you guys don't? This is reproducible for me. I don't see anything like that in security settings either.

Exactly to see where your setup may differ, we asked you to reboot in safe mode and try their, and to create a new user account (not in safe mode) and try that.

I tried with shorter passwords, it is possible to paste up to 63 characters into the password prompt when joining a WiFi network.
According to the specification, WPA2 passwords can have a length of up to 63 characters (German Wikipedia, English Wikipedia), the password prompt on Sonoma seems to be in line with that.
